# Will ANOVA work for spatial data?

Tags: correlation, anova, dataset, spatial

I have 16 variables separated into columns with 12 observations each.
Each row represents a point along a sampling transect, so for example, A2, B2, C2, and so on are all different measurements but from the same point in space.

I'm trying to find out if (and how) these different variables correlate, but it seems like a lot of tests I'm seeing are for replicate observations that produce an average, not data in space. I know ANOVA calculates variance which retains some of the information regarding spatial variation, but you would lose information like, for example, measurements 1 and 4  increase at point 7, but measurement 2 does not.

This might be a little long-winded, but I don't know statistics well so I'm explaining it as well as I can.
Thanks!

Comment: The ANOVA model uses some assumptions on the data, which I'm almost certain you can't use here. How about starting with a correlation matrix?

Comment: @Spätzle For the input into my correlation, if I select the entire arrays of 12 points, will it only compare adjacent ones or all of them?

Comment: I don't know where you hold your data, but most statistical programs are able to provide the whole correlation matrix (rather than for a single pair at a time). It is even possibly quite easily in Excel: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/01/23/correlation-excel-coefficient-matrix-graph/#make-correlation-matrix